# How do I use a ng-repeat with a Div inside a Angular-UI modal

Tags: angularjs

I have a form inside a Angular Modal. I am adding a new Customer with Customer employees. The default display is 1 employee, so I have added a button that gives the option of adding another Employee. I assumed that adding a ng-repeat would do the the trick but It is not working. It will not load the Div that the ng-repeat is in. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2pcwcss0zkLueELkh0N?p=preview)

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" style="width:initial" ng-repeat="employee in addMoreEmployees">
    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
        <label style="">First Name:</label>
        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeFirstName" type="text">
        <label style="margin-left:55px">Phone:</label>
        <input class="spacing-inputs" style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeePhoneNumber" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
        <label style="margin-left:3px">Last Name:</label>
        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeLastName" type="text">
        <label style="margin-left:71px">Cell:</label>
        <input class="spacing-inputs" style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeCellNumber" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
        <label style="margin-left:37px">Email:</label>
        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeEmail" type="text">
        <label style="margin-left:72px">Fax:</label>
        <input class="spacing-inputs" style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeFaxNumber" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
        <label style="margin-left:45px">Title:</label>
        <select style="width:150px;height:27px" ng-model="selectedCustomerEmployee.CustomerEmployeeRole">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="PM">PM</option>
            <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
            <option value="Superintendent">Superintendent</option>
        </select>
    </div><br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="addMoreEmployees.push({id: addMoreEmployees.length + 1})" value=" Add Another Employee">
</div>
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, but since the list is initially empty, you don't see anything (including the add employee button).  Add this to line 30 in example.js and you will see it show up right:

```
$scope.addMoreEmployees = [{}];
```

Comment: easy enough! thanks. now do you have any idea why in the plunkr the ng-repeat works perfect. But in my project, when I click Add Another Employee it adds it to the right of the modal, then when I click again it puts it in the right place? i am attaching a picture. thanks

Comment: The reason why you have the weird alignment issues is because you aren't using the bootstrap grid styling properly.  You need to encapsulate your `col-xs-12` inside of a `row`.  But then you also need to remove the `container` class and that causes other issues with your layout.  That's really a separate styling issue.